# Build Nested Object in Loop with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, loops

I am trying to create the following nested object inside a for loop using JavaScript which then gets pushed to an existing array:

```
            _spec = {
                _key: {
                    type: _clHndl.getFieldType(_f),
                    editable: true,
                    validation: {
                        required: _clHndl.isRequired(_f),
                        min: 10
                    }
                }
            };

            _arr.push(_spec);
```

The _key field is dynamic (changes every iteration), I want the identifier of the nested item _key to be the actual value that _key contains in the iteration. Right now it just makes each one '_key' when I use JSON.stringify() to inspect it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Search SO for "JavaScript create dynamic key".

Comment: I know how to make dynamic keys, but in a nested form like this, I'm not sure. I couldn't find an example of this specific context on SO.

Comment: It's no different for nested keys, though yours isn't really nested. It's at the top level of the `spec` object, so it'll be the same as most other examples given. `spec = {}; spec[my_dynamic_key] = {type:...};`

Comment: Cheers! That did the trick. Post it as the answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key isn't really nested *(it's at the top level of the outer object)*, though it wouldn't really be different if it was.

To create a dynamic key, use the square bracket version of the *member operator*.

```
spec = {}; 

spec[my_dynamic_key] = {
    type: _clHndl.getFieldType(_f),
    editable: true,
    validation: {
        required: _clHndl.isRequired(_f),
        min: 10
    }
}
```